# The first page of the bibliography does not follow page number format

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, page-numbering, bold

Apology for asking a simple question (I couldn't find a direct answer from searching). The first page number inside the bibliography looks like

[image]

The other pages have the page number bolded,

[image]

[image]

How do I adjust the TEX file so that the page number inside the bibliography is bolded?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=6mm, bottom=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
breakatwhitespace=false,         
breaklines=true,                 
captionpos=b,                    
keepspaces=true,                 
numbers=left,                    
numbersep=5pt,                  
showspaces=false,                
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,                  
tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{axionstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
  \cfoot{\Large \textbf{\thepage}} % for example
}


\title{COMPUTATIONAL METHODS FOR THE RIEMANN ZETA FUNCTION}
\author{Axion004}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble} %????
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{axionstyle}
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\section*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}


\nocite{•}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\bibliography{RiemannTEX}
\pagestyle{axionstyle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}{\ifbool{firstbib}{\thispagestyle{fancy}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the etoolbox package to modify the behaviour of the first \bibitem and to issue the instruction \thispagestyle.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}{\ifbool{firstbib}{\thispagestyle{fancy}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}
```

Modify the end of the TEX file

```
\end{flushleft}
\nocite{•}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\newbool{firstbib}
\booltrue{firstbib}
\preto{\bibitem}{\ifbool{firstbib}{\thispagestyle{axionstyle}\setbool{firstbib}{false}}{}}
\bibliography{RiemannTEX}
\pagestyle{axionstyle}
\end{document}
```